# Best way to improve UDP transfer speeds with Python?

Tags: python, performance, sockets, udp

I have written a Python program for sending and receiving large files over UDP. Right now, I can hit speeds of about .01GB/s when transferring between two computers on a 10 Gigabit Ethernet cable. I'm looking to improve that speed significantly, but I'm unsure what the best approach is.

For what it's worth, I **MUST USE UDP** for the transfer. The program I wrote is merely a test for a larger project, and the device sending the data for that project can't utilize a TCP stream. Additionally, I'm primarily focused on the best way to receive datagrams quickly, or at least the best way of ensuring that the receiving end isn't where any bottlenecks occur.

Right now, my program works by chunking up a large file into several pieces that will become the datagrams to be sent. These datagrams are sent, and then the receiver does some stuff to ensure that it got the proper data and orders it accordingly.

Sending Code (stripped down to basics)

```
buf = 32000  #Size of each chunk/packet
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host ="127.0.0.1"
port = 5005
addr = (host,port)    

def read_in_chunks(infile, chunk_size=buf):
"""Chunk the file before we send it.
Arguments:
infile -- the file to chunk
chunk_size -- the size of the chunk in bytes (default 32KB)
"""
    while True:
        chunk = infile.read(chunk_size)
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
        else:
            # The chunk was empty, which means we're at the end of the file
            return

def run():
    for chunk in read_in_chunks(f):
        if(s.sendto(chunk,addr) and s.sendto(id,addr)):
            #Some acknowledgment stuff - removed for clarity (also noted to not impact performance)
            local_ID += 1
```

Receiving Code:

```
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
buf = 32000  # Buffer size in bytes for each chunk
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  # Internet
                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

try:
    while(dataChunk):
        actualNumChunks += 1
        f.write(dataChunk)
        sock.settimeout(2)
        dataChunk, addr = sock.recvfrom(buf)
        packID, junkAddr = sock.recvfrom(buf)
        packIDString = str(packID)
except socket.timeout:
    f.close()
    sock.close()
    print "File received!"  # --KEEP
    print "A total of " + str(actualNumChunks) +" chunks were received"            --KEEP
```

I'm not sure if optimizing my code is the issue (yet to be tested), or if there is another (better?) way of getting increased speed for the file transfer. I apologize if the details here are sparse, but let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks!

Comment: use mmap(python library) for faster I/O. calculate max. MTU to send more bytes/packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some approaches to try:

1. Varied packet sizes (depending on [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit), might cause the chunk to be fragmented to several packets, or might be too small to optimally use the pipe)
2. Read the file to memory (the network speed might be 10gbps, but the disk is way slower, especially if it isn't an SSD - typically an order of magnitude or more slower), start sending after it has all been cached. You can try sending a the same block of data many times to check if this is the bottleneck.
3. Compression might help. ZLIB is very very very fast, and would mean you could transfer a lot more data in way less time,

Other points:

- Packet loss and ordering might make a proper transfer problematic, even in a simple 1-to-1 link. You'll need error-detection/retry functionality for this to work.
- Kernel/User mode changes might slow you down (doubt it, and this is super micro-optimization)

Comment: Thanks. A new notes: I have tinkered around with packet sizes and changing the MTU, and they appear to work, however when I actually tested the program with the 10GigE connection, I had to use a severely reduced packet size (~14000 vs the original 32000 that worked on the local 127 IP). The MTU max is about 9000 or so for the NIC we have. Also, for point 2, do you mean that I should read in the file completely before sending? Also, could you describe the test approach you mentioned a bit more? And for point 3, are you suggesting to send the compressed file as a whole or make compressed chunks?

Comment: 1. You can modify the MTU for both the source and destination NICs. 2. Try testing if this is the bottleneck by building one chunk of data and sending it in many packets, as if the file is composed of infinite repetitions of this chunk of data. That would mean you read the data from the RAM and not from the disk, and should show you whether that is the bottleneck, or if lies somewhere else. 3. Compressed chunks would probably work almost as well as the full file, and would mean you can start sending immediately - so I'd say compress the chunks.

Comment: Please let us know what your results are, and also mark this question as answered if you feel you got your answer.

Comment: Changed the MTU on both systems during the original test, but it didn't seem to have the desired effect. I'll test with the other changes today, but I think you've provided me with a much better sense of direction thus far. Thanks!

Comment: While the suggestions you made were valid and helpful, is there anything I can do from the receiving end to increase transfer speed? Your suggestions lean more towards the sending side (which is helpful for testing purposes). Essentially, I want to be able to ensure that the receiving end will not be the bottleneck.

Comment: Sorry for the latest response. If we're talking JUST the transfer, how about you drop the incoming packets rather than writing them to disk? You see, any link in the chain can be the bottleneck, the limitation on the total velocity.

Answer (score 0):

For your receiver, you do file write which could be a bottleneck.  A few things to try would be write all your "dataChunk" to a Queue.  Then have a separate thread or process (multiprocessing) that reads from this Queue that does the write to a file.  This would offload the file write IO from your while loop and would likely allow you to process more packets.